# An explanation to a set theory question involving sets, unions and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I do understand the question description but I don't understand what it wants, especially the "at least one" and "at most" vs "exactly". Can someone elaborate? Thanks in advance.

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $C = AB' + A'B$ is a set containing those elements which are in $A$ but not in $B$ and those elements which are in $B$ but not in $A$. Thus if $x ∈ C$ then $x ∈ A$ or $x ∈ B$ but not in both since $(AB')(A'B) = \phi$ . If $A$ and $B$ are possible outcomes of an experiment or set of experiments, then $(A'B + AB')$ represents the event that one of the outcomes $A$ or $B$ will occur, but not both.
If $A$ and $B$ are statements, the expression $AB' + A'B = I$ means either $A$ is a true statement or $B$ is a true statement, but not both $A$ and $B$ are true statements, with $I$ the "universally" true statement.
What sets involving unions, and intersections describe the following situations?

(a) Both $A$ and $B$ but not $C$.

(b) All of $A, B, C$.

(c) At least one of $A, B, C$.

(d) At least two of $A, B, C$.

(e) At most one. of $A, B, C$.

(f) Exactly one of $A, B, C$.

(g) None of $A, B, C$.

Comment: "At least two of $A,B,C$" means two or three, i.e. any of $ABC'$ or $AB'C$ or $A'BC$ or $ABC$, so you could take the union of those intersections, but I suspect you may be supposed to give an answer as simple as possible.

Comment: So for instance, when I say at least one of $A,B,C$, does that imply that if we are going to study the first case -which is one of the three event happened- that ALSO the other two didn't happen? meaning $AB'C' \cup A'BC' \cup A'B'C$ and also take the union of the other two cases which are 2 of the 3 events happening BUT not the the third, and then union of all events happening. I think I'm confused because firstly I'm not sure that when we have multiple cases inside each case I should use the union and secondly cause $C \subset A+B$

Comment: $AB'C' \cup A'BC' \cup A'B'C$ is when exactly one happens, so is situation (f). So situation (c) is the union of situation (d) as described in my earlier comment and situation (f) as described in your comment.    It can be simplified substantially: for example it should be obvious $A'B'C = \emptyset$.